# UDP connections from website

Tags: web, udp

Is there any way to start a UDP connection from within a website?

So that users can connect to a server listening for UDP packets while being on my website?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection, for a start. Clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control over the server and the web application running on the server it can be done. If you don't have such control firewall settings or other kind of restrictions you don't control might limit what you can do.